# Angular not invalidate parent form if child form manually set invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with parent form invalidation in angular - when child form is manually set to invalid, parent form still remains valid.

Here is jsFiddle with simple example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y5bp8rea/4/)

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="exampleController">    
    Parent Form            
    <form name="parentForm">          
        <input type="text" required ng-model="input" name="input"/>   
  <span ng-if="parentForm.$invalid">NG-INVALID</span>
  <span ng-if="parentForm.$valid">NG-VALID</span>
        <br>
        Nested form 
  <ng-form name="nestedForm">           
    <br>
    <button type="button" ng-click="setValidity(nestedForm)">Set invalid</button>
          <span ng-if="nestedForm.$invalid">NG-INVALID</span>
          <span ng-if="nestedForm.$valid">NG-VALID</span> 
  </ng-form>
</form>
```

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);
demoApp.controller('exampleController', function ($scope) {   
     $scope.setValidity = function(classicNested){
         classicNested.$invalid = !classicNested.$invalid;
         classicNested.$valid = !classicNested.$valid;
     }; 
});
```

Is this right approach? Iam not sure why it is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly why [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) has [$setValidity](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setValidity) method. It makes sure to adjust validity of parent form too if there is any:

```
$scope.setValidity = function(classicNested) {
    classicNested.$setValidity('nested', classicNested.$invalid);
};
```